# Selecting rows from DF1 where column values match values from a column from DF2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This problem has been solved (I think). Excel was the problem and not python after all. The below code should work for my needs and doesn't seem to be dropping rows after all.

[Rows Highlighted in yellow are the rows I want to select in DF1. The selection should be made based on the values in column_2 of DF1 that match the values of column_1 of DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyOCB.png)

Here was my preferred solution using Pandas package in python after a lot of trail and error/searching:

```
NEW_MATCHED_DF1 = DF1.loc[DF1['column 2'].isin(DF2['column_1'])]
```

The problem I am seeing is that when I compare my results to what happens in excel when I do the same thing, I am getting almost double the results and I think that my python technique is dropping duplicates. Of course, it is possible that I am doing something wrong in excel, or excel is incorrect for some other reason, but it is something I have verified in the past and much more familiar with excel so I am suspecting that it is more likely that I am doing something wrong in python. EXCEL IS THE PROBLEM AFTER ALL!! :/

Ultimately, I would like to use python to select any and all rows in DF1 where column_2 of DF1 matches column_1 of DF2. Excel is absurdly slow and I would like to move away from using excel for manipulating large dataframes.

I appreciate any help or directions to help. I really haven't been able to figure out if my code is in fact dropping duplicates and/or if there is another solution that I can be confident that wont do this.

Comment: looks right to me... can you include an example where you don't get the expected results?

Comment: Thank you for saying that the above code looks right. This, in addition to the code suggested below, has compelled me to do another check of the excel document and I see that there is in fact an error with this particular excel file and only this one ( I am not experiencing the same problem elsewhere). You are right and the code, I think, is good as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
list_df2 = df2['column1'].unique().tolist()
df1['matching_rows'] = np.where(df1['column2'].isin(list_df2),'Match','No Match')
```

And then create a new dataframe with the matches:

```
matched_df = df1[df1['matching_rows']=='Match']
```

Comment: Thank you! I performed these steps and I got the same results as before, which also matched my results from another technique I tried in python. The issue is in fact excel after all and my concerns about dropping rows with python have been significantly reduced! Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: You are welcome. If this resolved your issue, please accept the answer so that it's closed.

Comment: Hehe I think you need to click on the 'tick' next to the answer, instead of writing 'SOLVED' :) Thank you.

Comment: got it, accepted and thanks for the reminder/direction on that.

Comment: hahha you saw that! Yeah I am struggling with my first post it seems lol